# GCP and powerBI connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi

Are there any latency issues with data when GCP and Power BI are connected? what are the solutions to mitigate this issue, I have come across few articles that suggest using an Azure data lake between GCP and POWER BI which will reduce the latency issue. Any other suggestions or recommendations on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Which GCP products are you using?

Comment: BIG QUERY , Data Catalog

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want to achieve? You want to deploy PowerBi Server Report on GCE? `PowerBi` is Microsoft/Azure service, but you are able to connect different data sources like `BigQuery` from `GCP` or other cloud providers.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS,  Yes Power BI has Big Query Native connection. As it is a cloud to cloud connection between (Azure to GCP), is there latency issue?

What is the work around to avoid latency issue as we have seen this as a concern raised in many discussion forums.